# SQL Date extraction month and year

Tags: sql, date-format

The date format is 2018-02-04 , i would like to select the month and year from this to preferably get February, 2018, ill take 2018-02

the format is date/timestamp in postreg

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Refer to this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to provide a minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: The answer will depend on which DBMS you actually use, and the 'data type' of that information. ( is it a timestamp? Date? Strng?) This is because date functions differ dramatically for each vendor. Add a tag to your question e.g. postgres, mssql

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

- If you're using MySQL, you can use `DATE_FORMAT` to format date as specified:

  ```sql
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') FROM Table
  ```

  Check the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to find out more.
- Otherwise, assuming the date format is **YYYY-MM-DD**, what you can do is simply **CAST** date column to a string format and use [`LEFT()`](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/left-function.php) function to extract only the year and the month:

  ```
  SELECT LEFT(CAST(date as varchar), 7) from Table
  ```

Comment: i think its on postgresql , that didn't work on my platform

Comment: I've added an alternative you can use to extract the year and the month, from a specified date format.